# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "wikis" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, devise

I have no idea where to go from here.

**Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.3.8, Devise, Heroku 7.16.7**

App works great locally and deploys successfully to Heroku. When I visit the live app the home page populates as expected and the about page is accessible. I have a wikis index link and when I try to access it I get the wiki error below. Signing in is not required to view the index page.

I get the same error when I click on the sign-in or sign-up links. Schema shows a table created for both models.

Things I have tried:

- Deploying from a test branch after commenting out devise_for: users, pushing to Heroku so the migrations would run, subsequently uncomment devise_for: users and pushing agin to Heroku. No luck.
- I tried rake db:reset. No luck.
- I looked for and did not find any reference to either Rails model in my factories files.
- RAILS_ENV=test heroku rake db:migrate

WIKI ERROR

```
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414883+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "wikis" does not exist
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414885+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  ORDER BY created_at DESC
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414887+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414888+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  ORDER BY created_at DESC):
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414890+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/policies/wiki_policy.rb:42:in `resolve'
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414892+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/wikis_controller.rb:26:in `index'
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414893+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-13T00:08:10.414895+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Sign-In / Sign-Up Error

```
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468548+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468550+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468552+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468553+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468555+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468557+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468558+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468560+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468561+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468564+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2018-12-13T00:09:49.468565+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

**spec/factories/wikis.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :wiki do
    title "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    private false
    user
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'sample_user@google.com'
    password 'sample_password'
  end
end
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you confirm migration ran successfully on heroku?

Answer (score 3):

The following set of statements about your deployment situation assumes a normally-configured rails app.

Your project is dealing with three separate deployments, and each deployment has its own database (and hence its own database migration state).  Your three environments are (labels arbitrary):

- "test":  Runs on your local machine, with a local database, using RAILS_ENV=test in the command line or set implicitly by the command such as "rake test"
- "development":  Runs on your local machine, with a local database (*separate than* your local test database, as you can see by viewing `database/config.yml`)
- "heroku":  Run on Heroku's servers, with a database on Heroku's servers

Here's how you run the migrations in each of these separate deployments:

- "test":  `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`  (environment variable configured Rails, and then Rails.env is used to select a configuration from database.yml)
- "development":  `rake db:migrate`  ("development" is the default Rails environment)
- "heroku":  `heroku run rake db:migrate`    <---- Probably your solution.

My best guess is that you need to run that last command in order to ensure the migrations have been applied (including the migration called CreateWikis) to the database in your "heroku" deployment.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for providing valuable input. Learning and relearning everyday. @Luke Griffiths your hunch was spot on. Executing heroku run rake db:migrate did the job. For future readers in my situation:  run heroku config to ensure your db is set. You should see DATABASE_URL :    postgres://……. Once confirmed execute the above mentioned command.  Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that

1. you set up the database on Heroku?
2. that the migrations are running?

If it runs locally, and you receive the error `PG::UndefinedTable` this seems to be a missing migration.

For 2. you can add a `Procfile` (no extension) to your app root directory and simply put:

`web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
release: bundle exec rails db:migrate`

this will automatically run your migrations on deploy, see here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase

Just deploying to Heroku will not migrate your database automatically. I would not try to manually log into the Heroku console to run the migrations. You will forget to do that at some point, and bang your head on the error messages :-)